# Allow "Invalid" Characters in Member Account Email? Apostrophe

Tags: members, email

There is a particular member in my site that needs access but her corporate email that is attached to her account has an apostrophe in it. How do I allow EE to allow apostrophes in emails for member accounts?

Comment: If it was me I would be getting her tech department to create her an alias without the apostrophe. Would save a lot of hassle.

Comment: That was my first thought, but this person works for a giant multi-national oil company who's less likely to change their email stuff any time soon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to allow the apostrophe, I had to hack the core code. Specifically, a CodeIgniter helper within:

/system/codeigniter/system/helpers/email_helper.php

In there, find around line 40 this:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $address)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Then replace that line with this instead:

```
return ( ! preg_match("/^([a-z0-9\+_\-']+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-']+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/ix", $address)) ? FALSE : TRUE;
```

Found the particular regex in an old EE Forum Thread here:
http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/84711/

Anything wrong with this approach or the expression used?

Comment: Yup, I would just do this and document it in a 'hacks.txt' in the site root for reference. :)

Answer (score 1):

Incase someone else comes to this post.. this has heen resolved in the developer version of codeigniter.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/3116

Be sure to also update the Form_validation class as the email validation function there is different from the email_helper functions.